# Nodejs wait till async function completes and print the results

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to wait on the HTTP POST request to complete and then return response to the caller function. I am getting Undefined when I print the received results.

I have defined post method as below:

```
// httpFile.js 
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    getPostResult: async function(params) {
        console.log("getPostResult async called...");
        var result = await axios.post("https://post.some.url", params)
        .then ((response) => {
            console.log("getPostResult async success");
            return {response.data.param};
        })
        .catch ((error) => { 
            console.log("getPostResult async failed");
            return {error.response.data.param};
        });
    }
}
```

And I am calling it in this way:

```
// someFile.js
const httpFile = require('./httpFile');

// Called on some ext. event
async function getPostResult() {  

   var params = {var: 1};
   var result = await httpFile.getPostResult(params);
   
   // Getting Undefined
   console.log("Done Result: " + JSON.stringify(result)); 
}
```

I don't want to handle the `.then` and `.catch` in the calling function as I want to return the different values based on the POST result.

How should I wait for the response and get the return results.
In the above code I am getting the log statements as expected and "Done Result" get printed at the very end after the 'getPostResult' returns.

Comment: What do you expect `getPostResult` to return when it doesn't have a `return` statement?

Comment: Why are you mixing `await` and `then()`?

Comment: "*I am getting Undefined when I print the received results.*" two major problems in the code: 1. `getPostResult()` does not return anything. You need to use `return result` or just `return  axios.post( /* ... */ )`. 2. `return {response.data.param};` and `return {error.response.data.param};` are both syntactically invalid. An additional problem which is not as big: try to avoid mixing `async`/`await` and the promise API.

Comment: Are you using ES Modules or CommonJS Modules? Top level `await` doesn't work with CJS.

Comment: @SSM Please refer updated questions.  As per my understanding "getPostResult" won't return until `then` or `catch` is not called as `= await axios.post` will wait till request is either success or fail. So I have not added return at the end of the function `getPostResult`.

Comment: @User7723337 That's true, but `return` is not just making the function return but also specifies what _value_ to return. Without a `return` statement in the function itself, it will return `undefined` because you never specify _what_ it should return, so when it reaches the end it returns nothing.

Comment: If that is the case then answer by "bogdanoff" will also return undefined. Function returns when call return from the function no matter if it is at end or where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using both `await` & `.then` thats why it returns undefined.

this is how it should look

```js
// httpFile.js
const axios = require('axios')

module.exports = {
  getPostResult: async function (params) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('https://post.some.url', params)
      return res.data
    } catch (error) {
      // I wouldn't recommend catching error, 
      // since there is no way to distinguish between response & error
      return error.response.data
    }
  },
}
```

if you want to catch error outside of this function then this is way to go.

```
 getPostResult: async function (params) {
      const res = await axios.post('https://post.some.url', params)
      return res.data
  },
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the `try catch` so I have used `then catch`. Is there any other way other than try catch?

Comment: @User7723337 no, its the preferred way to go

Comment: @User7723337 why you even try to avoid it? why dont u like it?

Comment: @User7723337 Sure, you could just not use async/await and not benefit from the improved logic flow it provides. It is simply syntactic sugar over promises, afterall